# find column who has no corresponding rows in another table

Tags: mysql

Friends i have a problem
I have two tables channel and level

channel table

```
channel_id, manufacturer_id
```

level table

```
level_id,channel_id,sort_order
```

All channels have certain number of levels in them so like if channel has 4 rows level might have 20.

I want to know which channel has no levels at all. I have tried various solutions from stackoverflow.com but none worked for me as all of them return an empty set but I still have channels with no levels in the database. Please can anybody help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do anti join something as

```
select 
c.* from channel c 
left join level l on l.channel_id = c.channel_id
where l.channel_id is null
```

Comment: Thanks.. but this still gave me a empty result set

Comment: Are you sure that some channel does not have any record in the level table ? If it does not have `any record` in the 2nd table then the above query must work.

Comment: The result gives me an empty set

Comment: @Abhil chakraborty. Thanks it worked